# Android game logic problem

Tags: java, android

I'm currently creating a game and have a problem which I think I know why it is occurring but not entirely sure and even if I knew, don't know how to solve.
I have a 2D array 10 x 10 and have a "player" class that takes up a tile.
Now, I have created 2 instances of the player and move them around via swiping.
Around the edges I have put "walls" that the player cannot walk through and everything works fine, until I remove a wall.
Once I remove a wall and move the character/player to the edge of the screen, the player cannot go any further.
The problem occurs here, where the second instance of the player is not at the edge of the screen but say 2 tiles from the first instance of "player" who is at the edge.
If I try moving them further into the direction of the edge, I understand that the first instance of player wouldn't move or do anything but the second instance of player should still move, but it won't.

This is the code that executed when the user swipes:

```
if (player.getArrayX() - 1 != player2.getArrayX()) {
    player.moveLeft();
} else if (player.getArrayX() - 1 == player2.getArrayX() && player.getArrayY() != player2.getArrayY()) {
    player.moveLeft();
}

if (player2.getArrayX() - 1 != player.getArrayX()) {
    player2.moveLeft();
} else if (player2.getArrayX() - 1 == player.getArrayX() && player2.getArrayY() != player.getArrayY()) {
    player2.moveLeft();
}
```

In the player class I have:

```
public void moveLeft() {
    if (alive) {
        switch (levelMaster.getLevel1(getArrayX() - 1, getArrayY())) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            subX(); // basically moves player left
            setArrayX(getArrayX() - 1); // shifts x coord of player 1 within tilemap
            Log.d("semajhan", "x: " + getArrayX());
            break;
        case 9:
            subX();
            setArrayX(getArrayX() - 1);
            setAlive(false);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on the matter or further insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So many questions... What is `player.getArrayX()`. What is `subX()`. What does `setArray()` do. What does `getLeve1` return. Right now this question is completely unanswerable and it looks like you have a pretty messy design.

Comment: getArrayX() returns the x coord of the player. subX() subtracts the tile width, setArrayX() sets the player's new x coord, and getLevel returns a 2d tile map id at location (x, y). I really don't see how these have anything to do with the question I asked as all of these methods work perfectly fine. I was just wondering if the player instance was not moving because of something to do with the first player instance hitting the edge of the tile map.

Comment: I'm still confused about what `subX()` does. Also, what do the tile map ids mean? I'm guessing that 0 is a wall, 1 is an open space, and 9 means that the coordinates were invalid?

Comment: all subX() does is subtract the width of a tile from the x position of "player" so that the player moves. the tile ids are: 0 wall, 1 walkable, and 9 is just something unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding an if else statement:

```
public int getLevel1(int i, int j) {

    int[][] level = {
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 8, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 9, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
    };
    if (i >= 0 && i <= 9 && j >= 0 && j <= 14) {
        return level[j][i];
    } else {
        return 10;
    }
}
```